# Kendo Editable Grid column attribute parseFormats is not working as expected

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to make date column accept two formats using parseformats attribute, but it seems not picking up, please advise.
**Scenario**: When I input 10/10/19 it is showing inccorect date message. But when I input 10/10/2019, its working as no errors and displays in the format.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
  toolbar: ["save"],
  columns: [{
    field: "name"
   },
   {
    field: "age",
    format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
    parseFormats: ["MM/dd/yyyy", "MM/dd/yy"]
   }
  ],
  dataSource: {
   data: [{
     id: 1,
     name: "Jane Doe",
     age: "11/11/2019"
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     name: "John Doe",
     age: "10/10/2018"
    }
   ],
   schema: {
    model: {
     id: "id",
     fields: {
      age: {
       type: "date"
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
  editable: true
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
       <div id="grid"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: parseFormats is working as expected for me. Can you please add the grid code?

Comment: I am getting age is not a valid date when i try to enter 2 year date formats, why is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/eHaCeJAk)

```js
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
  toolbar: ["save"],
  columns: [{
    field: "name"
   },
   {
    field: "age",
    format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
    parseFormats: ["MM/dd/yyyy", "MM/dd/yy"]
   }
  ],
  dataSource: {
   data: [{
     id: 1,
     name: "Jane Doe",
     age: "11/11/2019"
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     name: "John Doe",
     age: "10/10/2018"
    }
   ],
   schema: {
    model: {
     id: "id",
     fields: {
      age: {
             parse: function (value) {
                var dt = kendo.parseDate(value,["MM/dd/yyyy", "MM/dd/yy"]);
                return kendo.toString(dt, "MM/dd/yyyy");   
               },
              validation: {
                 ageValidation: function (value) {
                 var dt = kendo.parseDate(value.val(),["MM/dd/yyyy", "MM/dd/yy"]);
                  value.attr("data-ageValidation-msg", "age is not valid date")
                  return dt !== null;
              }
              }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
  editable: true
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
       <div id="grid"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your help....it seems in model you added handler for parsing formats and setting back, not sure then why grid columns has that config or why that mentioned in docs?

Comment: I think the problem is on the validation of the type 'date'. I searched if I found a way to make him accept multiple formats, not having found it, I defined a new validation that would accept it. I hope it can help you!